# Области видимости в новом языке программирования

Tags: дизайн-языка

Я разрабатываю язык программирования, возник вопрос про области видимости.
Допустим, я пишу модуль, в котором есть структура С1, и мне понадобилось импортировать модуль, который называется С1. Более того, в обеих С1 могут быть члены с одинаковыми именами.
Как ЯП лучше обходиться с такими ситуациями?

Comment: Наиболее интуитивна  ситуация, когда модуль, тип (структура данных) и переменная могут иметь одинаковые имена. Тут нет неоднозначности. Переменные с общей областью видимости и одинаковыми именами (даже если они разного типа) лучше всегда явно объявлять общими. Так  программисту будет понятней.

Comment: Предусмотрите возможность замены имени в момент импорта. `import numpy` вводит глобальное имя модуля `numpy`. `import numpy as np` вводит глобальное имя `np`. Содержимое в обоих случаях одно и то же. Пример подразумевает что вы импортируете только одно имя - имя модуля. Для доступа к частям модуля используется конструкция `.` (`numpy.array`, `np.array`). У программиста есть возможность позже убрать имя модуля при обращении к его частям: `array = np.array`.